# Error when opening Odoo 10 Enterprise Point of Sale app after Power Failure

Tags: windows, postgresql, odoo

I am using Odoo 10.0 Enterprise

Due to a terminal that was not properly closed, and a power failure, I now receives the following error when entering the POS app

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 675, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 331, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 119, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 324, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 933, in **call**
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 820, in search_read
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 842, in do_search_read
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 4686, in search_read
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3012, in read
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 5201, in **getitem**
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 869, in **get**
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 980, in determine_value
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 935, in compute_value
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 926, in _compute_value
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\point_of_sale\models\pos_config.py", line 162, in _compute_current_session_user
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 863, in **get**
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 4813, in ensure_one
**ValueError: Expected singleton: pos.session(918, 917)**

There are about 700 transactions that I know of that is not posted yet on 1 users name.

Could somebody help me solve this problem.

It seems that I have to fix something in the database but I don't have an idea what to do

Regards,

Jaques

Answer (score 1):

So after 48 hours of no sleep I have figured this out:

```
System:        Odoo 10 Enterprise

 Platform:    Windows Server 2008 r2


 Actions:    

         1.    Delete all sessions in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A\Odoo\sessions

         2.    Open pgAdmin III

         3.    Use Object browser and browse to:

                                     a.    PostgreSQL (Enter Password)

                                     b.    Database   (Your Database name)

                                     c.    Schemas

                                     d.    public

                                     e.    Tables

                                     f.    pos_session

        4.    On the right window, select Properties at the top

        5.   Right click on rows           

        6.    Select View Data

        7.    Select View all rows

        8.    Scroll down to the bottom and then to the right and find the column called state

        9.    Working your way upwards change and make sure all is closed

        10.    When done, select save.

        11. Test the system
```

Regards,

Jaques